# Select a particular feature from feature Layer to find intersects in Find Existing Location analysis using ArcGIS API for javascript

Tags: arcgis, analysis, arcgis-js-api, spatial-query, location-based

I have create a custom HTML page for find existing location using ArcGIS API . Following this link [find existing location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NTBz.jpg)
The API code is able to find attribute and spatial query from existing feature layer. But my feature layer size is too large and I want to find the intersect of only selected target feature from specific feature layer.[Highlight the target feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NTBz.jpg)

Comment: Let me see If I understand you, you want to get the intersection geometries between a given geometry and a FeatureLayer?

Comment: hi @cabesuon  sorry for late reply. I got the geometry but I want to highlight the target feature in feature layer which intersects that geometry